# Select specified fields in mongodb and create , update and return the fields if they don't exist

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I have some fields i want to select in mongodb using yii2. I also want to find out whether they exist and if they dont i want to create the fields and populate them with a default value like zero.

After the update, i want the select statement to return the fields i just created and their data if they didn't exists before.

Currently, mongodb returns an empty array when i run this code and this is normal behavior according to the docs

```
public function actionTestTheory()
    {
    $email = 'example@gmail.com';
    
    $collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('properties');
    $current_timestamp = Yii::$app->formatter->asTimestamp(date('Y-d-m h:i:s'));
   
   //Create Properties List Object
   
   $properties_query = new Query;
    
    $properties_query->select(['one','two','three','four'])
        ->from('properties')
        ->where(['email' => $email,'seven' => 'complete']);
    $rows = $properties_query->all();

    echo json_encode($rows);
    }
```

How do i do this in mongodb?

Comment: either loop over $rows before output and add them or merge $rows into a default result

Comment: I have so many fields so first solving the question from mongodb perspective first would be the best then loop where necessary.